# Does Sqlite on the Iphone reorder database rows when I delete a row?

Tags: iphone, sqlite

I'm quite new to iphone programming. I would like some information with you. Here is the structure of my database:

```
ID_song : auto-int (primary key)
txt_song : text
```

When we do delete some data from a table view, and when the data is deleted from the SQLite database, let's say I have only 3 songs in my database

```
id_song:1 txt_song:Song_A
id_song:2 txt_song:Song_B <------ (To be deleted)
id_song:3 txt_song:Song_C
```

After deleting the rows, does the data in the table looks like:

```
id_song:1 txt_song:Song_A
id_song:3 txt_song:Song_C
```

or

```
id_song:1 txt_song:Song_A
id_song:2 txt_song:Song_C
```

I mean, does sqlite reorganise the index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why would it do that ?
First of all, that could make a huge performance hit and a real risk to violate the integrity of the data.
Changing the primary key, means that all related foreign keys have to be changed as well.

Answer (score 1):

No, it does not. (which you probably could've figured out in about 5 minutes by trying it yourself. :))

Answer (score 1):

No.  No Database will rewrite an ID field after deletion of a row.  If you wish to number your songs, you will need to do this yourself in code.

Answer (score 1):

it looks like

```
id_song:1 txt_song:Song_A
id_song:3 txt_song:Song_C
```